# Can't Json parse Array BACK after Json stringify it to cookie

Tags: jquery, arrays, parsing, cookies, stringify

When i save json to the cookie i can't parse it back :(

```
var checkoutArray = [{"id":"1021397549","prod-name":"2015 новый шик! горячая распродажа бесплатная доставка сексуальные женщины красочные птицы шифон рубашка форме крыла летучей мыши широкий блузки свободного покроя топы","cost":134,"sku":"14:200001438#8;5:361385","pcs":"1","ship-num":"2","ship-name":"e-EMS","ship-cost":796,"img":"http:\/\/i01.i.aliimg.com\/wsphoto\/v15\/1021397549_1\/2015-новый-шик-горячая-распродажа-бесплатная-доставка-сексуальные-женщины-красочные-птицы-шифон-рубашка-форме-крыла-летучей.jpg","aviable":"990","sku-html":"<img class=\"color\" height=\"26\" width=\"26\" src=\"http:\/\/i01.i.aliimg.com\/wsphoto\/sku\/v12\/1021397549\/1021397549_200001438\/Хаки-2015-новый-шик-горячая-распродажа-бесплатная-доставка-сексуальные-женщины-красочные-птицы-шифон-рубашка-форме-крыла-летучей.jpg_50x50.jpg\" title=\"8\" bigpic=\"http:\/\/i01.i.aliimg.com\/wsphoto\/sku\/v12\/1021397549\/1021397549_200001438\/Хаки-2015-новый-шик-горячая-распродажа-бесплатная-доставка-сексуальные-женщины-красочные-птицы-шифон-рубашка-форме-крыла-летучей.jpg\"\/><span>L<\/span>"},{"id":"2028047220","prod-name":"2015 новый шик! горячая распродажа бесплатная доставка сексуальные женщины красочные птицы шифон рубашка форме крыла летучей мыши широкий блузки свободного покроя топы 14003","cost":135,"sku":"","pcs":"2","ship-num":"2","ship-name":"China Post Registered Air Mail","ship-cost":110,"img":"http:\/\/i00.i.aliimg.com\/wsphoto\/v0\/2028047220_1\/2015-новый-шик-горячая-распродажа-бесплатная-доставка-сексуальные-женщины-красочные-птицы-шифон-рубашка-форме-крыла-летучей.jpg","aviable":"998","sku-html":""},{"id":"802048809","prod-name":"Дизайнер искусственного из двух частей кружева шифон блузка рубашка с кардиган для женщин 2015 весна мода дамы свободного покроя топы","cost":582,"sku":"","pcs":"1","ship-num":"3","ship-name":"Fedex IE","ship-cost":3865,"img":"http:\/\/i01.i.aliimg.com\/wsphoto\/v0\/802048809\/Дизайнер-искусственного-из-двух-частей-кружева-шифон-блузка-рубашка-с-кардиган-для-женщин-2015-весна-мода.jpg","aviable":"918","sku-html":""}];          

$.cookie("wishlist", JSON.stringify(checkoutArray));
console.log( $.cookie("wishlist") );
var checkoutArray = JSON.parse($.cookie("wishlist"));


var checkoutArray = JSON.parse($.cookie("wishlist"));
jQuery.each(checkoutArray, function (i, wishlistID) { 
checkoutArrayDom += '<br>'+ wishlistID + '<br>';                        
});
```

In Chrome console i get this

> "[{\"id\":\"1021397549\",\"prod-name\":\"2015 новый шик! горячая
>   распродажа бесплатная доставка сексуальные женщины красочные птицы
>   шифон рубашка форме крыла летучей мыши широкий блузки свободного
>   покроя
>   топы\",\"cost\":134,\"sku\":\"14:200001438#8;5:361385\",\"pcs\":\"1\",\"ship-num\":\"2\",\"ship-name\":\"e-EMS\",\"ship-cost\":796,\"img\":\"http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v15/1021397549_1/2015-новый-шик-горячая-распродажа-бесплатная-доставка-сексуальные-женщины-красочные-птицы-шифон-рубашка-форме-крыла-летучей.jpg\",\"aviable\":\"990\",\"sku-html\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"802048809\",\"prod-name\":\"Дизайнер
>   искусственного из двух частей кружева шифон блузка рубашка с кардиган
>   для женщин 2015 весна мода дамы свободного покроя
>   топы\",\"cost\":582,\"sku\":\"\",\"pcs\":\"1\",\"ship-num\":\"3\",\"ship-name\":\"Fedex
>   IE\",\"ship-cost\":3865,\"img\":\"http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/802048809/Дизайнер-искусственного-из-двух-частей-кружева-шифон-блузка-рубашка-с-кардиган-для-женщин-2015-весна-мода.jpg\",\"aviable\":\"918\",\"sku-html\":\"\"}]"
>
> jquery-latest.min.js:2
>
> > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to
> >     search for '966' in [{"id":"1021397549","prod-name":"2015 новый шик!
> >     горячая распродажа бесплатная доставка сексуальные женщины красочные
> >     птицы шифон рубашка форме крыла летучей мыши широкий блузки свободного
> >     покроя
> >     топы","cost":134,"sku":"14:200001438#8;5:361385","pcs":"1","ship-num":"2","ship-name":"e-EMS","ship-cost":796,"img":"http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v15/1021397549_1/2015-новый-шик-горячая-распродажа-бесплатная-доставка-сексуальные-женщины-красочные-птицы-шифон-рубашка-форме-крыла-летучей.jpg","aviable":"990","sku-html":""},{"id":"802048809","prod-name":"Дизайнер
> >     искусственного из двух частей кружева шифон блузка рубашка с кардиган
> >     для женщин 2015 весна мода дамы свободного покроя
> >     топы","cost":582,"sku":"","pcs":"1","ship-num":"3","ship-name":"Fedex
> >     IE","ship-cost":3865,"img":"http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/802048809/Дизайнер-искусственного-из-двух-частей-кружева-шифон-блузка-рубашка-с-кардиган-для-женщин-2015-весна-мода.jpg","aviable":"918","sku-html":""}]

But when i do same thing without saving cookie `$.cookie("wishlist", JSON.stringify(checkoutArray)); checkoutArray = JSON.parse($.cookie("wishlist"));`, just using `checkoutArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(checkoutArray));` everything works fine!

Comment: are you sure you aren't exceeding cookie size limit?

Comment: that is too much data for cookies, think about using localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It sincerely depends on which browser is executing this code because a browser has its specification about what length of cookie it can store.

I sincerely feel that you are crossing that limit.

Here is table which gives you the details about most of the browsers.

[image]

and check out this [Link](http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/), to know more about your browser..

Comment: solution in my hands, i am looking for local storage now)

`Storage.prototype.setObj = function(key, obj) {
    return this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj))
}
Storage.prototype.getObj = function(key) {
    return JSON.parse(this.getItem(key))
}`